# Cannot Break Out of a "While" loop

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, char, segmentation-fault

I am converting a 2-d `char` array into a 2-d `int` array, and I need to break out of the `while` loop if `\0` or `\n` comes in the string. This code gives segmentation fault.
Definition of `Array` is and the indices are less than 1000 and the 2-d `char` array `tempCharArray` is already stored. What is the problem with my code?

```
//Array[tempCount][1000];

for(int i=0;i<tempCount;i++)
{
   strtok(tempCharArray[i]," ");
   while(tempCharArray[i]!="\0" || tempCharArray[i]!="\n")
   {
      Array[i][arrayindex]=atoi(strtok(NULL," ");
      arrayindex++;
   }
   arrayindex=0;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile.

Comment: tempCharArray is a 2-d array,I need to look at the end of the string that is at location "i" of of tempCharArray[i]

Comment: I also have a strong feeling you're using non-standard VLAs. It honestly looks like a `std::vector<std::string>` would fit your needs much better.

Comment: @chris: question is tagged `C` so `std::vector<std::string>` is probably not an option.

Comment: @PaulR, Oh, didn't notice the C++ tag got removed. If the OP tagged it C++, they better be willing to use C++.

Answer (score 4):

You are a little mixed up (a) between char literals and string literals and (b) with your while loop logic.

Change this line:

```
while(tempCharArray[i]!="\0" || tempCharArray[i]!="\n")
```

to:

```
while(tempCharArray[i]!='\0' && tempCharArray[i]!='\n')
```

Note that your compiler should have warned you about mistake (a) - you do have warnings enabled, I hope ?

---

**Edit:** it seems from subsequent comments that `tempCharArray` may actually be an array of strings ? In that case you would need to do this to fix problem (a):

```
while(strcmp(tempCharArray[i],"")!=0 && strcmp(tempCharArray[i],"\n")!=0)
```

Note that you can not compare *strings* with `==` or `!=` - you need to use `strcmp`.

The logic bug and its fix still apply of course.

Comment: tempCharArray is a **2-d** array,I need to look at the end of the string that is at location **i** of of 'tempCharArray[i]'

Comment: OK - I've updated the answer now - please make sure you include this sort of information in your questions in future.

Comment: `char *tempCharArray[tempCount]`

Comment: Still the segmentation fault.

Comment: You'll need to use your debugger to identify the cause of the seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

If `tempCharArray` is the `char` array, you are trying to compare a single character with a complete string. That will not do what you want it to. Instead compare it to a *character* literal:

```
while(tempCharArray[i]!='\0' || tempCharArray[i]!='\n')
```

Note the use of *single* quotes instead of double.

Comment: I think the `||` also needs to be `&&` ?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use `&&` instead of `||` because the loop continues **as long as** the condition is true (and this is—in your case—as long as `tempCharArray[i]` is `'\0'` **and** `'\n'`
- You need to use single quotes, because you compare character literals

This leads to

```
while (tempCharArray[i] != '\0' && tempCharArray[i] != '\n')
```